# Use wxPython button to refresh ListCtrl box

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a ListCtrl box that links to my SQL database and pulls a list of part numbers from it to allow the user to choose to update certain ones. I want to let the user refresh the list so they can view the updated list.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import sys
import wx
import wx.adv

dflist = ['Test1'],['Test2']


class compwin(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,'',
                          size=(300,300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        self.part = None
        #textbox printout

        #Prompts for Update Field
        wx.TextCtrl(panel,value = "Update Part:",size=(100,20),pos=(5,10),style=wx.TE_READONLY|wx.BORDER_NONE)
        def ComboBox(panel):
            self.ComboUp = wx.ListCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(150,125),pos=(10,30),style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_SORT_ASCENDING)
            self.ComboUp.InsertColumn(0,"Select a Part Number:",wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT)
            self.ComboUp.SetColumnWidth(0,150)
            for Part in dflist:
                self.ComboUp.Append((Part))
            return
        ComboBox(panel)

        #define buttons
        self.refresh = wx.Button(panel,label ="Refresh", name ="3",pos=(200,180))
        
        #bindings for panel
   
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnClick_Refresh,self.refresh)

############################ REFRESH BUTTON #########################################
    def OnClick_Refresh(self,e):
        self.ComboUp.Destroy()
        wx.BeginBusyCursor()
        self.ComboUp = wx.ListCtrl(self,wx.ID_ANY, size=(150,125),pos=(10,10),style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_SORT_ASCENDING)
        self.ComboUp.InsertColumn(0,"Select a Part Number:",wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT)
        self.ComboUp.SetColumnWidth(0,150)
        for Part in dflist:
            self.ComboUp.Append((Part))        
        wx.EndBusyCursor()

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = compwin()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I've tried running it as a nested function inside the def Onclick_Refresh button with

```
j = compwin()
j.ComboBox()
```

but I receive the error

> AttributeError: 'compwin' object has no attribute 'ComboBox'. Did you mean: 'ComboUp'?

How can I get my list to refresh with this button click? I thought destroying the window and re-executing the definition for ListCtrl would be the easiest way but I'm misunderstanding something crucial in order to get that to work.

Comment: First of all make `ComboBox` a normal method instead of a local function. Then you can call it as `self.ComboBox()`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, Sorry, I'm unsure what you mean. Do you mean removing the def altogether, or making a separate class outside of the main class?

Comment: Move it out of the `__init__` function to the same level as `__init__` and add the usual `self` parameter.

Comment: With all due respect, your code is a mess (spaghetti). When you are asking people to give up their time to help you (which we are happy to do) please meet them half way. One thing you could do is to produce a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). all the business about engine and sql is irrelevant to your problem and we cannot reproduce it. I'm not prepared to even look at it unless you get rid of that bloat

Comment: @Psionman completely understand. I've taught myself all of this in about 3 weeks so I have a lot to learn. This is the minimal reproducible example aside from the SQL database, I just was unsure if that made a difference in the function I'm trying to execute. I'll update that.

Comment: @Psionman :) Any comment that starts "With all due respect..." is going to be damning about whatever it is. ;) I agree by the way and upvoted your comment.

Comment: I take on board @RolfofSaxony's comment, and in a spirit of penitence  I have attempted to refactor your code into a more pythonic structure (inevitably opinionated) and you can find it [here](https://pastebin.com/nWyLC3rQ) . If you need more help or want clarification please ask :)

Comment: @Psionman This was incredibly gracious of you, thank you so much. I'll look through this and make sure my work is easier to read and go through in the future. Thank you for your help and guidance, it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding the code in the question and using code from a previous question/answer, we can demonstrate, that you simply need to clear the `ListCtrl` and repopulate it.

```
import wx

dflist = [
          ["123","Widget 1", "w101"],["456","Widget 2", "w2091"],["789","Widget 3", "w3000"],["132","Widget 4", "w404"],
          ["465","Widget X", "x555"]
         ]

dflist2 = [
          ["998","Widget 998", "w999"],["999","Widget 999", "w999"]
         ]

class compwin(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,'Shortage Sheet Compiler v0.1',
                          size=(600,300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self,-1)

        #textbox printout

        #Prompts for Update Field
        wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, value="Update Part?", size=(150,20), pos=(25,20), style=wx.TE_READONLY|wx.BORDER_NONE)

        #Text Boxes for Update Field
        self.Combobox = wx.ListCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(400, -1), pos=(25, 50), style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.Combobox.InsertColumn(0, "Item", wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT)
        self.Combobox.InsertColumn(1, "Name", wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT)
        self.Combobox.InsertColumn(2, "Part Number", wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT)
        self.Combobox.SetColumnWidth(1, 150)
        self.Combobox.SetColumnWidth(2, 150)

        for item in dflist:
            self.Combobox.Append((item[0], item[1], item[2]))

        #define buttons
        self.refresh = wx.Button(panel, -1, label ="Refresh", name ="3", pos=(450,180))

        #bindings for panel

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClickRefresh, self.refresh)

    def OnClickRefresh(self, event):
        self.Combobox.DeleteAllItems()
        for item in dflist2:
            self.Combobox.Append((item[0], item[1], item[2]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = compwin()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: God, thank you. It's always so simple. Is there a place I can read up on this more? I always look through the documentation  before I ask but can't ever find what you find.

Comment: @Anima_et_Animus Here https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/4.2.1/ you will find downloads for the documenttion and demos for all the major features. Install them on your machine and you'll always have access to them.